# Can a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ have nonzero homology in dimension $\geq n$?

Tags: homology-cohomology

The title basically says it all. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be any subset. If we impose some restrictions on $A$ (like $A$ being a neighborhood retract) one can show that $A$ cannot have homology in dimensions $\geq n$ (e.g. using barycentric subdivision). However, what can we say if we do not impose any restrictions on $A$?

Comment: Maybe look at Milnor's paper (basically, take a certain wedge of spheres and singular homology using rational coefficients): https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-02/S0002-9939-1962-0137110-9/S0002-9939-1962-0137110-9.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which has nonzero homology in infinitely many degrees.  Specifically, this is true of the 2-dimensional "Hawaiian earring" which consists of infinitely many shrinking 2-spheres which intersect at a point.  More generally, for any $n\geq 2$, the $n$-dimensional Hawaiian earring has nonzero homology in infinitely many degrees.  This is a theorem of Barratt and Milnor in

> *Barratt, M. G.; Milnor, John W.*, [**An example of anomalous singular homology**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2034486), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 13, 293-297 (1962). [ZBL0111.35401](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0111.35401).

On the other hand, a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ always has trivial homology in degrees $\geq 2$.  This is a theorem of Andreas Zastrow which as far as I can tell has never been published but appears in [this unpublished preprint](http://at.yorku.ca/i/d/e/b/11.htm).  (The corresponding result for $\mathbb{R}^1$ is also rather trivially true.)